# Which folders are unnecessary while deploying a play! app?

Tags: deployment, playframework

I have finally made a production worthy app with play, and use the `play war -o foo` command to create an exploded war. However, its size goes on to 30 MB and there are a lot of folders included. I develop in eclipse, so there are some eclipse folders too. Below is a list of the folders I have. Can anyone help me out with the unnecessary folders? I have zeroed in on the app, conf, public and lib folders. Is my assumption correct?

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── daily
│   │   └── monthly
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── encrypt
│   │   ├── file
│   │   ├── login
│   │   └── mail
│   ├── playground
│   └── views
│       ├── Application
│       └── errors
├── conf
├── eclipse
│   └── classes
│       ├── controllers
│       ├── jobs
│       │   ├── daily
│       │   └── monthly
│       ├── models
│       │   ├── encrypt
│       │   ├── file
│       │   ├── login
│       │   └── mail
│       └── playground
├── lib
├── logs
├── public
│   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   └── tests
│   │   │       ├── unit
│   │   │       └── vendor
│   │   └── less
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
├── test
└── tmp
    ├── bytecode
    │   └── DEV
    └── classes
        ├── controllers
        ├── helpers
        ├── jobs
        │   ├── daily
        │   └── monthly
        ├── models
        │   ├── encrypt
        │   ├── file
        │   ├── login
        │   └── mail
        └── playground
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All folders in `app`, `conf`, `lib` and `public` should be kept in your war. Maybe should add `precompiled`

Comment: Also removed the tmp folder and some others that I wasn't using.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete your tmp folder as well, try to use play clean on your project.